# Transmission of the image using BPSK

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, communication, modulation

Input image needs to be modulated and transmitted and finally detected using BPSK.

```
M = 2; %Modulation order 2 for BPSK 
randn('state',200); % initializing the randn() function
imdata = imread('lenna.pgm'); 
bdata = de2bi(imdata);         
sizec = size(bdata,1);         % height
sizer = size(bdata,2);         % width
nbits = sizec*sizer;            % number of bits in the image
msg = double(reshape(bdata,nbits,1));
```

The following code is meant to modulate the input image and display the demodulated output.The resultant output,when i run the code,I get a blank image.Need help in figuring out what I have missed or where I have gone wrong.

```
%modulate
txpsk = pskmod(msg,M);

%noise
phasenoise = randn(nbits,1)*0.015;
rxpsk = txpsk.*exp(2i*pi*phasenoise);

%demodulate
recovpsk = pskdemod(rxpsk,M);
reshape1rxpsk = reshape(recovpsk,sizec,sizer);
reshape2rxpsk = bi2de(reshape1rxpsk);
finalout= reshape(reshape2rxpsk,size(imdata,1),size(imdata,2));
imshow(finalout)
```

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get an idea of how to maximise your chances of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PGM file consists of a sequence of one or more PGM images. Each image has a header structure, containing such information, as width, height e.t.c. After modulation you add a noise to your signal. Therefore, the demodulated signal may contain errors. If this errors corrupts header information of image - this may lead to blank image output. Try to comment lines

```
%phasenoise = randn(nbits,1)*0.015;
%rxpsk = txpsk.*exp(2i*pi*phasenoise);
```

Comment: commenting lines has no effect on output.

Comment: @pybear Try to compare imdata and finalout, and bdata and reshape1rxpsk. Something like sum(imdata-fianlout).